# How to send message from javascript to awesomium?

Tags: c#, javascript, awesomium

*I am working on an application which uses Awesomium. I already have done the big parts of the project but now I am stucked at this point.*

Situation:
My web application receives message via socket.io. When I receive message in web application, I want to forward this message to awesomium, because c# app. does not know when the message comes.

I really have no idea about this. I know I can implement socket.io project in c# application but we already have an web application which is working and I want to embed this web app. into the c# app.

I really need to know, how to send message from javascript to awesomium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what version of Awesomium you are using. A similiar question has been asked before and has a brilliant answer: [Can I call application methods from JavaScript in Awesomium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280727/can-i-call-application-methods-from-javascript-in-awesomium)