# Capturing a GET request from an embedded browser control

Tags: c#, awesomium

I'm using [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) to embed a web page in a windows application.  I'm trying to hook into the GET from our REST api so that when the page requests data I can access the JSON response in my C# code.

I've tried hooking into `WebControl.TargetURLChanged` to no avail.  I've also tried hooking into that same event on the active `WebSession.View`.

Is there a way, with [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) or otherwise, to capture HTTP GETs made from a hosted web page and access the response data?

Comment: You could look into the Fiddle api. http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore

Comment: Yeah, that's a decent suggestion and one I was considering myself.  I'd rather see if it's possible with the tech I'm using already first.

Comment: What about using javascript integration http://wiki.awesomium.com/general-use/introduction-to-javascript-integration.html

Comment: @Papasmile - that looks promising!  Of course that type isn't documented on the .NET side of the wiki, only the C++ side.

I'll give it a shot and if it works I'll let you know so you can move your comment to an answer.

Comment: @Papasmile, I've been unable to get the actual object using JSValue.  The .NET version doesn't have a ToObject method, and the ToString just returns the type (e.g., "{object}" for "window).

Comment: Sorry you are having a tough time... try function callbacks (passing your return in a another javascript function) to return a string whatever you want.

Comment: Also check out on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280727/can-i-call-application-methods-from-javascript-in-awesomium/13382677#13382677

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that other question.  I was able to get the sample on that question working, and I think when I combine that with the ResourceInterceptor I can get the functionality I want.

Create an answer like "use function callbacks like show in this link" as an answer and I'll give you the internet points.  Thanks!